# Calling another controller within a controller if already logged in

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller, undefined

I have a login controller, where I do a check wether he is logged in or not like so

```
if($logged_in){
    $this->load->view('profile_view'); 
}
else{
    $this->index();
}
```

Like you can see I'm loading a view if im not logged in. But instead of loading a view I'd rather have it that I load a controller that loads that view, because I want to send data from the controller to the view.

So I want to do something like this

```
 if($logged_in){
    $this->load->controller('profile_controller'); 
 }
```

and in my profile controller put this

```
function index(){
    $logged_in =  $this->logged_in->is_logged_in();

    if($logged_in){
        $this->load->model('profile_model');
        if($query = $this->profile_model->getAllUserInfo()){
            $data['records'] = $query;
            $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "you don't have access on this page";
    }
}
```

But It seems loading a controller from a controller isn't possible! So how can I create my view while sending data to it?

Comment: Is `redirect()` an option? I suggest redirect guests to the URI which points to that Controller.

Comment: Yeah redirect() is an option didn't know that, that method existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how Ben Edmunds authentication library handles it.

```
if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        redirect('auth/login');
    }
```

Ion_Auth Lobrary - http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#logged_in